# how to Display date in textbox onselecting dropdown?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In my application am using a drop down menu for tree selection. And i have used one textbox which is readonly. If the user selects a tree from that drop down menu then corresponding date  of that particular tree should get displayed in that textbox. 
for ex. In database

```
tree_no       Date of Spathe opening
125           26/05/2010
144           08/03/1999
105           18/05/2010
```

If the user selects tree 105 using dropdown the immediately date 18/05/2010 should get displayed in that textbox

I have written a code that fetches the data correctly. the problem that i face is while displaying the data.
data gets displayed in textbox only when a user clicks in that textbox(that's because i have used onclick event for it) Please help me to modify the code so that the data gets displayed in textbox and it should remain in that  textbox until and unless user selects another tree from the drop down menu
Code in aspx page

```
<div class="list_text_left">
    Tree :</div>
<div class="list_text_right">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddTreeNo" CssClass="title_dropdown" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddTreeNo_SelectedIndexChanged" />
</div>
<div class="list_text_left_new1">
    Date Of Spathe Opening:</div>
<div class="list_text_left_new" style="width: 86px; font-weight: normal;">
    <asp:TextBox ID="dtActv" runat="server" CssClass="textbox1" onfocus="Change(this, event)"
        onblur="Change(this, event)" onkeypress="return keydown(this.id,event);" ValidationGroup="MKE" />
    <input type="hidden" id="dte" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hBlockID" />
</div>
```

Page behind code

```
dtActv.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");

protected void ddTreeNo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    check(ddpBlock.SelectedValue, ddTreeNo.SelectedValue);
    Response.Write("Selected value");
}

public void check(string blocknum, string tree) {

    string tre = ddTreeNo.SelectedValue;
    string lstd = "", dtemas = "";
    string str = " select talltree_master.dt_spatheopen ";
    str = str + "  from talltree_master ";
    str = str + " where talltree_master.block_id =" + blocknum + " and talltree_master.dtdied is NULL and talltree_master.talltree_id =" + tree + "";
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(str, cn);
    try {
        cn.Open();
        OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read()) {
            if (dr.IsDBNull(0)) {
                t1 = "";
            } else {
                tt = dr.GetDate(0);

                lstd = tt.ToShortDateString();

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Response.Write(ex);

    } finally {
        cn.Close();
    }


    dtActv.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";

    string block_id = lstd;
    hBlockID.Value = block_id.ToString();

}
```

javascript code for onclick event in aspx page

```
function clearTextBox(dtActv) {
    var hBlockID = document.getElementById('<%= hBlockID.ClientID %>').value;
    document.getElementById(dtActv).value = hBlockID;
}
```

Please modify my code.

Comment: In the HTML you have supplied the `clearTextBox` javascript function is never used so why have you added it? Also have you tried setting `AutoPostBack=true` in the DropdownList properties?

Comment: In code behind page there is a function public void check(string blocknum, string tree){ dtActv.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)"; } over there i call clearTextBox function

Comment: why dont you assign value direct to textbox?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are changing the dropdown and getting the value via code-behind (C#) and then you are waiting for the `onclick` of the textbox event before you set the textbox to be the same as the hidden `hBlock` element.

Why not simply set the value of the textbox in the code behind of the page?

```
    string block_id = lstd;
    hBlockID.Value = block_id.ToString();
    dtActv.Text = block_id.ToString();
```

Then you do not need to use the `onclick` javascript event to set the value as this is done automatically when the page posts back.

So your `check` method would become :

```
public void check(string blocknum, string tree) {
    string tre = ddTreeNo.SelectedValue;
    string lstd = "", dtemas = "";
    string str = " select talltree_master.dt_spatheopen ";
    str = str + "  from talltree_master ";
    str = str + " where talltree_master.block_id =" + blocknum + " and talltree_master.dtdied is NULL and talltree_master.talltree_id =" + tree + "";
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(str, cn);
    try {
        cn.Open();
        OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read()) {
            if (dr.IsDBNull(0)) {
                t1 = "";
            } else {
                tt = dr.GetDate(0);

                lstd = tt.ToShortDateString();

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Response.Write(ex);

    } finally {
        cn.Close();
    }

    string block_id = lstd;
    hBlockID.Value = block_id.ToString();
    dtActv.Text = block_id.ToString();
}
```

And you can remove the javascript function.